# How to compare power of logarithm function $\log x$ with the power of $x$?

Tags: number-theory, logarithms, real-numbers

Let $r_1, r_2 \in \mathbb R$. Assume that $r_2<-2.$Can we find generic relation between $r_1$ and $r_2$ so that

$$ (\log N)^{r_1} N^{r_2} \ll N^{-2}? $$

Or What condition on $r_1$ ensure the above inequality?

Answer (score 1):

The relation is simply $r_2 < -2$; for any $\epsilon > 0$, $\log(N) = \mathcal O(N^\epsilon)$, so also $\log(N)^{r_1} = \mathcal O(N^{\epsilon r_1})$.

Comment: Thanks.   Where can I look at the the proof of the fact that $\log N \leq C N^{\epsilon}$ for any $\epsilon>0$?

Comment: @Learn, see e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663818/does-the-logarithm-function-grow-slower-than-any-polynomial).