# Test if the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\sqrt{n}-1}{\sqrt{n}} \right)^n$ converges or diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to test if the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\sqrt{n}-1}{\sqrt{n}} \right)^n$ converges or diverges. From my graphing calculator, it looks like each term in this series is nonnegative and is less than the corresponding term in the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1.5}}$ So I believe this series converges. But I am wondering if there is a more intuitive proof to show this series converges without using a calculator.

Comment: Hint: $(1-\frac1{\sqrt n})^{\sqrt n}$ tends to the constant $e^{-1}$; can you use that to get an upper bound for $(1-\frac1{\sqrt n})^n$?

Comment: @GregMartin Like $\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^\sqrt{n}$? I am not sure how this helps.

Comment: Perhaps $\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^\sqrt{n} \leq \left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^{\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor}$?  Do you know how many nonnegative integers $n$ satisfy $k = \lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor$ for a given nonnegative integer $k$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @Greg_Martin's hint. Note that

$$\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}-1}{\sqrt{n}} \right)^n=\left(\left(1+\frac{(-1)}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^\sqrt{n}\right)^\sqrt{n}$$

Since

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{(-1)}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^\sqrt{n}=\frac{1}{e}<\frac{1}{2}$$

there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq N$ implies

$$\left(1+\frac{(-1)}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^\sqrt{n}<\frac{1}{2}$$

But then for these $n$ we have

$$\left(\left(1+\frac{(-1)}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^\sqrt{n}\right)^\sqrt{n}<\frac{1}{2^\sqrt{n}}$$

Thus

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{\sqrt{n}-1}{\sqrt{n}} \right)^n=\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \left(\left(1+\frac{(-1)}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^\sqrt{n}\right)^\sqrt{n}+\sum_{n=N}^\infty \left(\left(1+\frac{(-1)}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^\sqrt{n}\right)^\sqrt{n}$$

$$<\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \left(\left(1+\frac{(-1)}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^\sqrt{n}\right)^\sqrt{n}+\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{2^\sqrt{n}}$$

The first sum is a finite sum while the second sum converges by the [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) since

$$\int_N^\infty\frac{1}{2^\sqrt{x}}dx=\frac{\sqrt{N}\ln(2)+1}{2^{\sqrt{N}-1}\ln^2(2)}$$

(see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%281%2F2%5Esqrt%28x%29%2Cx%2CN%2Cinfty%29)). We conclude

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{\sqrt{n}-1}{\sqrt{n}} \right)^n$$

converges.

---

EDIT: Here is the last step without the integral test. Note that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{2^\sqrt{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp\left(\ln\left(\frac{n^2}{2^\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)$$

$$=\exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{n^2}{2^\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)=\exp(\lim_{n\to\infty}(2\ln(n)-\sqrt{n}\ln(2)))$$

(by the continuity of the exponential). It is well known that $\ln(n)$ [grows slower than any power](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663818/does-the-logarithm-function-grow-slower-than-any-polynomial) of $n$. This implies

$$\exp(\lim_{n\to\infty}(2\ln(n)-\sqrt{n}\ln(2)))=\exp(-\infty)=0$$

(to make this step fully rigorous, simply not that if $a_n$ is a sequence such that $a_n\to-\infty$, then $e^{a_n}\to 0$). Thus, there exists $K\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq K$ implies

$$\frac{n^2}{2^\sqrt{n}}<1$$

Now, define $W=\max\{K,N\}$. Then the sum becomes

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\left(1+\frac{(-1)}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^\sqrt{n}\right)^\sqrt{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{W-1} \left(\left(1+\frac{(-1)}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^\sqrt{n}\right)^\sqrt{n}+\sum_{n=W}^{\infty} \left(\left(1+\frac{(-1)}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^\sqrt{n}\right)^\sqrt{n}$$

$$<\sum_{n=1}^{W-1} \left(\left(1+\frac{(-1)}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^\sqrt{n}\right)^\sqrt{n}+\sum_{n=W}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^\sqrt{n}}<\sum_{n=1}^{W-1} \left(\left(1+\frac{(-1)}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^\sqrt{n}\right)^\sqrt{n}+\sum_{n=W}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$$

The first sum is finite while the second some converges by the [p-test](http://www.math.com/tables/expansion/tests.htm).

Comment: It does make sense. But proving the series $\sum \frac{1}{2^{\sqrt{n}}}$ converges by integral test without a calculator is painful. I am studying this for a test and I can’t use a calculator unfortunately. But I am appreciated for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Let $a_n = \left( \frac{\sqrt{n}-1}{\sqrt{n}} \right)^n$. Then for $n \geq 2$, $$\log a_n = n \log \left( 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \right) = -\sqrt{n} + O \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \right),$$ which implies $a_n \leq C e^{-\sqrt{n}}$ for some fixed constant $C$ and all $n \geq 1$.

Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-\sqrt{n}}$ converges by [Limit Comparison Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-2}$, the original series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges as well.