# Can you prove that $\lim_{n \to -\infty}{ne^n} = 0$?

Tags: limits

Is it possible to show that $\lim_{n \to -\infty}{n^ke^n} = 0$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$?

I tried to prove this by induction but my attempt failed.

Comment: Think about how this question answers yours. How could you transform this question appropriately? [Does the logarithm function grow slower than any polynomial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663818/does-the-logarithm-function-grow-slower-than-any-polynomial)

Comment: Context?  From where are you starting? Is this in cal class stuff etc?  Hopital's rule is always popular (though one doesn't need it)...

Comment: @peterag could you tell what's wrong with my argument????

Comment: @Sumanta You're missing an exponent on $m$. You substituted $n=-m$, so should have used $n^k=(-m)^k = (-1)^k m^k$,  and not $(-1)^km$.

Comment: @Sumanta my comment was not addressing your comment! That said, it might not be obvious to the OP that $e^m \ge m^2/2$, or whether a proof was required - e.g., analysis course, or cal course... That kind of thing was in my mind with my suggestion to the OP for context.

Comment: $$\lim_{n\to-\infty}n^ke^n=\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{(-1)^k m^k}{e^m}=0$$ as $$\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{ m^k}{e^m}\leq\lim_{m\to \infty}\frac{m^k\cdot (k+1)!}{m^{k+1}}=0.$$ Note that $e^m=1+m+\frac{m}{2!}+...+\frac{m^k}{k!}+.....$ for the inequality.

Comment: After two suggestions from the comments.