# Area bounded by implicit function

Tags: asymptotics, area, implicit-function

The equation, $x^y = y^x  ~(x≠y)$ does not seem to have an elegant method to separate the variables. It is intuitive from the graph shown below (Desmos output) that it should have a convergent area bounded by the lines x = 1, y = 1. If the area does converge, are there any numerical methods to compute the same? Is there a closed form value to it? In general, what is the approach to identify whether or not the area bounded by a curve with its asymptotic curve converges or not?

[image]

Comment: Note: The red "curved" curve can be parametrized by $$(x,y)(t)=(t^{1/(t-1)}, t^{t/(t-1)}), \qquad t>0.$$ I am not sure how easy it is to proceed from there.

Comment: Using @MaximilianJanisch's parameterization, it seems the area diverges.  I checked $\int_0^1 (y-1)x'\,dt$ in Mathematica.  I think you can probably use the fact that the area between $x=1$, $y=1$, and $y=1+1/(x-1)$ diverges, since it appears to lie completely inside the region you describe.

Comment: There's a formula for computing the area under a curve given parametrically, but I think you'll have to compute compute the integral numerically (if in fact it converges).  See formula $10.2.7$ [here](https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/University_of_California_Davis/UCD_Mat_21C%3A_Multivariate_Calculus/10%3A_Parametric_Equations_and_Polar_Coordinates/10.2%3A_Calculus_with_Parametric_Curves#:~:text=The%20area%20between%20a%20parametric,%E2%80%B2(t)dt.)

Answer (score 1):

If $x^y=y^x$ for $x,y>0$, then we have by taking logarithms
$$\frac{\ln(x)}x=\frac{\ln(y)}y.$$

Let $K\overset{\text{Def.}}=\frac{\ln(x)}x$. Then we have the equation
$$K = \frac{\ln(y)}y.$$

Introducing $\tilde y \overset{\text{Def.}}=-\ln(y)$, we get $y=\exp(-\tilde y)$ and therefore $$\tilde y \exp(\tilde y)=-K.$$

The solution to the latter equation is usually denoted by $\tilde y = W(-K)$, where $W$ is called the [Lambert $W$ function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html).

Ignoring details with the multiple branches of the Lambert W function, if $x>e$, then a Taylor expansion gives that $$W(-K)=-K+O(K^2)$$ as $K\to0$.

Therefore, keeping in mind that $y=\exp(-\tilde y)$, the integral for the area for $x>e$ looks like
$$\int_{e}^\infty \exp(-W(-K))-1\,\mathrm dx=\int_e^\infty \exp\left(\frac{\ln(x)}x+O\left(\frac{\ln(x)^2}{x^2}\right)\right)-1\,\mathrm dx,$$ which diverges since $\exp(1+y)\ge y$ for all $y\in\mathbb R$.

---

More explicitly, the mentioned integral is bounded from below by $\int_e^\infty \ln(x)/x+O(\ln(x)^2/x^2)\,\mathrm dx$. Now, the $O$ term converges absolutely, since $\ln(x)$ is locally bounded for $x\ge e$ and [therefore](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1663818/631742) $\ln(x)\le C \sqrt[3] x$ for some $C>0$ and all $x\ge e$, which means that $\frac{\ln(x)^2}{x^2}\le C x^{-\frac 43}$. The latter has an anti-derivative that is globally bounded for $x\ge e$. Furthermore, since $\frac{\ln(x)}x\ge\frac 1x$ for all $x\ge e$, the integral of the first term diverges, so the whole thing diverges.

Comment: In fact, it is divergent: Use $\exp(x)\ge 1+x$. Currently I don’t have time to give a full formulation.

Comment: Using the definition of $W$ you have $\exp(-W(-K)) = \frac{W(-K)}{-K}$ and you already  have the asymptotic for $W(-K)$.