# Proving a function is Big-O of another function

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, asymptotics

So I'm trying to prove that $4^{log_{10}(n)}=O(\sqrt{n}log_{2}(n^3))$
This is what I did, but I'm not sure if it is correct
Firstly, $4^{\log_{10}(n)}$ can be rewritten as
$$4^{\log_{10}(n)}=2^{2\log_{10}(2)\lg(n)}=2^{2\lg(n)\log_{10}(2)}=n^{\log_{10}(4)}$$
Clearly, $0<\log_{10}(4)<1$
It is a known fact, and has been proven in Homework 1, that Big-O is transitive.
$$f(n)=\mbox{O}(g(n)) \mbox{ and } g(n)=\mbox{O}(h(n)) \Longrightarrow f(n)=\mbox{O}(h(n))$$
Let $f(n)=n^{\log_{10}(4)},\ g(n)=n$
Since $0<\log_{10}(4)<1$, then $n^{\log_{10}(4)} \leq n$ for all $n\geq0$ and $c \geq 1$
Thus, $n^{\log_{10}(4)}=\mbox{O}(n)$, or $f(n)=\mbox{O}(g(n))$
Now, $\sqrt{n} \leq \lg(n)$ for $n \geq 4$ and for $c \geq 0$
Multiplying $\sqrt{n}$ on both sides yields $n \leq \sqrt{n}\lg(n)$
Moreover, $\sqrt{n}\lg(n) \leq \sqrt{n}\lg(n^3)$
Hence, by the transitive property of inequalities, $n \leq \sqrt{n}\lg(n^3)$
If $\sqrt{n}\lg(n^3)$ is assigned to $h(n)$, then it can be concluded that $g(n)=\mbox{O}(h(n))$
Therefore, by the transitive property of Big-O, $f(n)=\mbox{O}(h(n))$, or $4^{\log_{10}(n)}=\mbox{O}(\sqrt{n}\lg(n^3))$

If it is incorrect, can anyone please guide me to a correct approach?

Comment: $\sqrt n \leq \lg n$ is not correct, it is the other way around. The logarithm grows much slower than the squre root (or any positive power of $n$). The original statement you are trying to prove is not true. Indeed $$
4^{\log _{10} n}  = n^{\log _{10} 4}  > n^{0.6}  \gg 3n^{0.5} \lg n = \sqrt n \lg (n^3 )
$$ for $n$ large enough.

Comment: But when I graph the functions is question, $\sqrt{n}lg(n^{3})$ is larger after $n=1.267$

Comment: It takes some time for it to take over. Try for example $n=10^{24}$ or greater. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663818/does-the-logarithm-function-grow-slower-than-any-polynomial