# Given $\alpha > 0$, find smallest $C > 0$ so that $\log(x) \leq C x^\alpha$ for all $x > 0$.

Tags: limits, polynomials, logarithms

It follows from $\lim_{x\to\infty} \log(x) / P(x) = 0$ for any polynomial $P$, that for any $C, \alpha > 0$, there exists $x^* > 0$ such that

$$
x > x^* \implies \log(x) \leq C x^{\alpha}.
$$

Typically when both $\alpha$ and $C$ are small, we end up with a situation covered in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663818/does-the-logarithm-function-grow-slower-than-any-polynomial). Namely the equation $\log(x) = Cx^{\alpha}$ has two solutions $x_1 \leq x_2$ with $x_* = x_2$ being gigantic.

It appears, however, that regardless of how small one chooses $\alpha$ to be, a "moderate" choice for $C$ is enough to mitigate the smallness of $\alpha$ - for instance when $\alpha = 1/10$ then  choosing $C \approx 3.678794$ pretty much closes the gap between $x_1$ and $x_2$. The length of the gap $x_2 - x_1$ becomes huge very quickly if a tiny bit smaller $C$ is chosen instead. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=3.678794x%5E%281%2F10%29+%3D+log%28x%29).

For a fixed $\alpha > 0$, I am interested in determining the smallest $C$ so that the two roots collide and annihilate each other, in the sense that the inequality holds for all positive $x$. Would it be possible to derive a formula for such $C$ explicitly? Any comments you might have will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the curves is
$$f(x) = C x^\alpha - \ln x$$

For this difference to reach exactly zero but never be negative, we require $f(x_0) = 0$ and $f'(x_0) = 0$ at some point $x_0 > 0$. (These are necessary but not sufficient conditions on showing $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x > 0$.)

The derivative is

$$ f'(x) = C \alpha x^{\alpha-1} - \frac{1}{x} $$

Then

$$ 0 = x_0 f'(x_0) = C \alpha x_0^\alpha - 1 $$
$$ 0 = f(x_0) = C x_0^\alpha - \ln x_0 = \frac{1}{\alpha} - \ln x_0 $$
$$ x_0 = e^{1/\alpha} $$
$$ C = \frac{1}{\alpha e} $$

This matches your example empirical result: if $\alpha = \frac{1}{10}$, then $C = \frac{10}{e} \approx 3.678794$.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you very much!