# Proving a function decays polynomially

Tags: real-analysis, functions, applications

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be such that $f(x)=O\left(\left(\frac{1}{\log x}\right)^{\lambda}\right)$ as $x\to\infty$ for some constant $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$. Can we prove that $f$ decays polynomially, that is, $f(x)=O\left(x^{-\mu}\right)$ for some $\mu>0$?

My idea was to expand in terms of a Taylor series, but this doesn't work since we don't have a Taylor expansion for $\log(x)$. If we had, for example, $f(x)=O(\log x)$ we could argue that since $\log x=O(x)$, we get such a result. But with $\frac{1}{\log x}$ there is no such analogue, so I am unsure how to proceed. Any ideas would be great!

Comment: I suspect you mean $\lambda > 0$, as otherwise $f$ is growing rather than decaying. But in any case, the statement is false. Recall that $\log(x)$ grows slower than $x^\mu$ for any $\mu > 0$. For the same reason, $1/\log(x)$ decays slower than $x^{-\mu}$ for any $\mu > 0$. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1663818/158213). Is there perhaps a mistake in your question?